# dynamic memory allocation using new operator , issue in type cast

Tags: c++

```
uint8_t hello = 50;    
uint8_t *data;

data = new uint8_t(hello); //issue when using "new"
data = (uint8_t*)malloc(hello); //worked fine
```

I want to allocate memory like above mentioned code. If I delete this data ptr at the end of the scope, there is some sort of memory leak. Moreover, have I allocated the memory correctly? Is there any casting needed like I did for malloc?

Comment: In C++ you should steer towards using `new`, avoiding `malloc` except for compatibility with existing C code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking to make a buffer of some particular size:

```
uint8_t *data = new uint8_t[hello];
```

Where `hello` is your size argument. Note the use of `[...]` instead of `(...)`. The second form is for constructor arguments when building one of something.

The original form creates an allocation for one `uint8_t` and populates that particular one with the value `50`. That's presumably not what you want, but it does work:

```
data = new uint8_t(hello);

std::cout << *data << std::endl;
```

This outputs `2` which is correct as that's the ASCII character 50.

> All that being said, for character buffers steer towards `std::string` and far, far away from C-style buffers if you can.

Comment: uint8_t *data = new uint8_t[hello]; - This worked. Now if I want to delete the memory, do I need to iterate through every element? What if I want to delete the memory outside the scope?

Comment: In C++ you pair `new[]` with `delete[]`, so eventually you'd call `delete[] data` to release that allocation. You can *only* operate on the allocation returned to you via `new[]`, not any variation on it, like `&data[n]`. The *exact* pointer you're given is the one you release. You can pass it around, but you must send it back to `delete[]` as-is.

Comment: Note that this memory management is done for you automatically with `std::vector<uint8_t>` which can be pre-sized and pre-populated with whatever you want.

Comment: Since I am using a vector, do I need to iterate through all the elements of that vector in order to free the memory or not? Big picture is, I have this pointer which is being assigned to an element of a structure and that structure is being pushed in a vector which is std::vector<struct>. So in order to free the vector (which is being used outside the scope of where "new" is done) I was wondering if vector gets freed on it's own or do I need to explicitly free it by iterating it over all the elements?

Comment: Asking that question is fine, but it's a sign you need to learn about the [RIAA principle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) that's the backbone of C++ memory management. In short, *if* you call `new[]` you *must* eventually call `delete[]`. If you call `new` you call `delete`. If you're using `std::vector` without `new` you *do not* call `delete` *unless* the elements in that vector were allocated via `new` *and* you're not using some kind of [pointer wrapper](https://en.cppreference.com/book/intro/smart_pointers) you can hand off the allocation to.

Comment: If you have allocations you basically need to unwind them, typically in the reverse order of their allocation. That's how C++ will do it with destructors for local variables.

Comment: @galaxy2096 There is almost never a good reason to use new and a vector. Use one of the other (preferably use vector) but not both. They are alternatives.